# How to remember code when you are working with a lot of languages?

Tags: programming-languages

Sometimes I work for a project that requires some programming languages for about 3 months, later I work for another project that requires a different set of languages. I know and studied of of these languages, but the problem is that I keep forgetting a lot of the details, and sometimes I have to re-read a book or watch online courses as a refresher and that takes time.

Is there a way that software programmers use to remember details or at least get up faster?

Comment: Don't worry about it, the details will stick automatically as you use them more often. Having to look them up again as you go is not a problem. The biggest issue I find myself running into is using language elements from one language in another and using keyboards shortcuts that works in one environment but not in the other. Like ending statements with semi-colons or diuble quotes vs single quotes. Often the compiler/interpreter will catch that but not always, it may mean something unintended. The tolerance/smartness of PowerShell is notorious. That is where you need to be careful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to learn a language over and over again.

**Keep cheat-sheets**, **make a repository of useful code-snippets** and **use text search tools** to search for text in your code base in order to recall how you did something in the past.

**What is really important is that you don't forget how to program (language agnostically) and thinking like a programmer.** Nobody is expected to memorize the syntax of all languages one has worked with. It's normal to get rusty in a language after years of not working with it.

But if you keep going back to the basics of a language over and over again it means you are not taking notes and you are not building a collection of cheat-sheets.

Note-taking for later reference and keeping cheat-sheets as well as being able to do text searches in your existing code-base is part of the job.

Also articipating in communities like Stack Overflow or Software Enginnering (StackExchange) not only searching existing answers but also asking new ones and even better helping others by answering questions as well, is a good way of keeping your skills honed.

Comment: +1 for "don't forget how to program".

Answer (score 0):

If a cheat sheet works for you, as @Tulains suggested, do so, and store it on the web in Dropbox, GitHub, etc.

For me, casually rereading / skimming a good, general "moderately detailed" book works best.  Yes, a physical paper book.  (I'm an older programmer). Know what you are weak at.  I always mix up each language's `foreach` style Iterator, (and their fancy functional iterators) whether it gets keys or values, if it is a copy, so I know I need refreshing there.  So when I'm switching to JavaScript, I always reread the Array section.  etc.

When switching to CSS, I reread about selectors, margins and borders.  YMMV.

And frankly, just Google the answer.  You'll usually end up here on Stack Overflow.